# $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

> Define $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$
>   Show that it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

I figured out that both $f_x$ and $f_y$ exists and are discontinuous at $(0,0)$  but can't say anything about differentiability of $f(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$ and also $f(x,y)$ looks like a continuous function!

Answer (score 5):

Recall that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if there exists a linear function $\ell$ and a function $h$ such that 
$$
f(x,y)=f(0,0)+\ell(x,y)+h(x,y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}h(x,y)=0. 
$$
Here $f(0,0)=0$, $f(x,0)=x$ and $f(0,y)=0$ hence, if such functions $\ell$ and $h$ exist, then $\ell(x,y)=x$ for every $(x,y)$.

But $f(x,x)=\frac12x$ hence $f(x,x)-f(0,0)-\ell(x,x)=-\frac12x$ and one would have $|h(x,x)|=\frac12$ for every $x\ne0$, hence $h(x,x)$ would not go to $0$ when $x\to0$.

Thus, $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: What about outside the origin?

Answer (score 4):

Were your function differentiable, it would be the case that if $f'(0;v)$ is the directional derivative at $0$ with direction $v$

$$f'(0;v+w)=f'(0;v)+f'(0,w)$$

Now let $v=(v_1,v_2)$ such that $v\neq 0$. Then

$$f'(0;v)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tv)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^3v_1^3}{t^3\lVert v\rVert ^2}=\frac{v_1^3}{\lVert v\rVert^2}$$

This is evidently not linear, hence your function cannot be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: shouldn't it be $f'(0;v+w)=f'(0;v)+f'(0;w)$ ?

Comment: @Kacper Yes, fixed.