# Show that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is differentiable and that directional derivatives are linear combinations of partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Consider $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ with $f(0,0)=0$:
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}.
$$
I need to show if $f$ is differentiable at $\vec 0$. One way of showing it, is noting that $f$ is homogeneous of degree 1. I have two questions about other approaches:

1) I would also like to show differentiability using the definition. I first calculated $D_1f(\vec0)=1$ and $D_2f(\vec 0)=0$. So I would need to show that for $\vec x=(x,y)\to (0,0)$, it holds that
$$
f(\vec x)-f(\vec 0)-x=o(\Vert\vec x\Vert).
$$
So basically I need
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.
$$
I don't know how to show this limit. I can't bound stuff like $x^2+y^2\leq y^2$, because that doesn't help me anywhere. Any tips?

*edit*

I made an error, it should have been:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},
$$
for which it is easy to show that this limit equals 0! So only my second question is still relevant (see below)

2) I also wanted to check if for $\vec u=(u_1,u_2)$, $D_{\vec u}f(\vec 0)$ is a linear combination of the partial derivatives. However, this doesn't seem to be true, for we have
$$
D_{\vec u}f(\vec 0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^3u_1^3}{t^3(u_1^2+u_2^2)}=\frac{u_1^3}{u_1^2+u_2^3}\neq u_1D_1f(\vec 0)=u_1.
$$
So did something go wrong calculating the directional derivatives?
$$
D_1f(\vec 0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^3}{t^3}=1
$$
and
$$
D_2f(\vec 0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{0}{t}=0.
$$
So how does the directional derivative not equal the linear combination of the partial derivatives, while $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: Perhaps your numerator is $-xy^2$ in part $1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes, you're right! I'll adjust it. Thank you

Comment: An older question about the same function: [$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478368).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step in Part $1$ is to use polar coordinates:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{(r^2\cos^2(\theta)+r^2\sin(\theta))^{3/2}}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)=\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta).
$$
Since different $\theta$'s give different limits, the function is not differentiable.  Therefore, there is no expectation that the gradients are a dot product.

Comment: Thanks! Would you also know where I made the mistake computing the directional and partial derivatives? The directional derivative doesn't seem to be a linear combination of the partial derivatives.

Comment: Wait, how do you get $r^{1/2}$? Shouldn't we get the following:
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{(r^2\cos^2(\theta)+r^2\sin^2(\theta))^{3/2}}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)
$$

Comment: Agreed, that's why the function is not differentiable!  Nice spotting.

Comment: oh, I see where I messed up. Homogeneity of degree >0 doesn't imply differentiability. It only means that $\lim_{\vec x\to\vec 0}f(\vec x)=0$. However, if the degree was $>1$, then our function would have been differentiable!

Comment: @ShaVuklia If the function isn’t differentiable, there’s no reason to expect that any directional derivatives that do exist are linear combinations of the partial derivatives (which are themselves just directional derivatives in specific directions).